# Problem after dual boot installation

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I installed Ubuntu a while ago in a dual boot. It worked ok with Windows ; but then my windows got a bug because of a virus.
Since then, I can only boot on Ubuntu, Windows just won't boot.
In the meanwhile, I can't modify anything on the part of my hard disk which is dedicated to windows ; I can read it but can't modify it, and I can't even do a new hard disk repartition.
How can I solve that ?
I fear a bit that by installing a new version of Ubuntu it should cause problems.
Can I just erase everything and install the new version of Ubuntu ?

thanks in advance

Comment: run `sudo update-grub` command on ubuntu terminal.And restart it.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can just format the drive which u installed ubuntu and install it freshly.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `parted`, GParted, or any other libparted-based program for partitioning, you can't modify in-use partitions. You can modify some partitions by unmounting them. GParted lets you do this -- right-click the partition and select "Unmount" from the menu. You can't unmount your Linux root (`/`) partition, though, so if you need to modify it, you'll need to boot with an emergency disc (the Ubuntu installer in its "try before installing" mode should work fine for this).

That said, the problems you've described are all Windows problems, and it's not clear to me that repartitioning will solve your problems. Chances are you can't write to the Windows partition from Linux because it was not properly unmounted. The only way to fix this problem is by running `CHKDSK` (or its GUI equivalents) from Windows. Because Windows won't boot, this puts you in a bit of a bind -- but as with resizing partitions with GParted, an emergency disc is the solution. This time, though, it must be a *Windows* emergency disc. I don't happen to have any URLs handy, but a Web search should turn them up. (Be wary, though; I'd be shocked if there are no third-party Windows recovery discs with malware. Download only from Microsoft or some other trusted source.)

Alternatively, if you don't want to keep Windows, you can use your existing read-only access to transfer your user files off of the Windows partition and then use GParted or `mkfs` to turn it into a Linux partition. You might even follow [this procedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving) to convert that space into a separate `/home` partition, which will make it safer and easier to do a fresh Linux installation without damaging your user files.